# How to disable WhatsApp notification from notification bar

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, 7.0-nougat, notification-bar

I have iVOOMi Me5 with Android 7.0. I have to stop WhatsApp notifications from the Notification Bar as following:

[image]

I have gone through settings but I didn’t find any option for making such change.

Regards
FewL

Comment: Long press on the any notification..

Answer (score 1):

Try Settings --> Apps(or equivalent to what it is on your device) --> scroll down to whatsapp. You should find notification settings there.